# loremru для webstorm

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, webstorm

Необходим аналог loremN, где N - число случайных слов. Прочитал документацию на сайте jetbrains по составлению live templates, потыкал методы, в итоге не нашёл чего-нибудь подходящего для решения задачи. Подскажите, кто сталкивался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В HTML/XML вы можете использовать [Emmet Lorem Ipsum](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/lorem-ipsum/) генератор: скажем, введите `lorem10.cls`, нажмите `Tab` - в результате получится `<div class="cls">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, odit!</div>`

См. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/emmet.html

Comment: Наверное вопрос неверно поняли, мне нужен loremru , то есть чтобы текст-рыба была русская, такого в сокращениях эммета нет в вебшторме, а как свою написать я не знаю